# sqljdbc_auth.dll was not found inside JAR. (under IntelliJ)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, sqljdbc, java.library.path

I cannot solve this problem:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /x64/sqljdbc_auth.dll was not found inside JAR.
at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteServer.setupDomainAuth(RemoteServer.java:131)
at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteServer.start(RemoteServer.java:55)
at com.intellij.database.remote.RemoteJdbcServer.main(RemoteJdbcServer.java:15)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /x64/sqljdbc_auth.dll was not found inside JAR.
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteServer.extractLibraryFromJar(RemoteServer.java:171)
    at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteServer.setupDomainAuth(RemoteServer.java:127)
    ... 2 more
```

I have copied `sqljdbc_auth.dll` in  `C:\Windows\System32` but its not working.

Answer (score 4):

If you have placed the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` library in your system path (which `C:\Windows\System32` would be), then you should be able to use integrated security to connect to a MSSQL database using the either the jtds or Microsoft JDBC driver.

The key for me was to leave the "Use Windows domain authentication" box **unchecked**, but then in the Advanced tab, switch the "*integratedSecurity*" property from false to **true**.

I'm running IntelliJ 14.1.6

Comment: doesn't work for me...

**Integrated authentication failed.**

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Thanks a lot @Nate!

Comment: This was it. Drop the checkbox setting and add set integratedSecurity=true inside Advanced tab. The integratedSecurity=true is not needed in the URL anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you download the Microsoft SQL Server driver from within IntelliJ IDEA, you will see that they have wrapped the x86/sqljdbc_auth.dll and x64/sqljdbc_auth.dll in a jar file and then added this jar to the classpath.
If you are offline, use `jar -cvf sqljdbc_auth.jar x*` to wrap the folders into a jar and add it manually to the classpath.